# How to delete an object from Javascript object

Tags: javascript

I'd like to delete an object element from an object. I have tried the following but it returns the same without deleting an element. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shinokada/z3ns49vj/4/). I am trying to delete clock object.
How can I delete it?

```
var position = '{"weather":{"id":"weather","x":0,"y":0,"width":12,"height":9},"google_calendar":{"id":"google_calendar","x":0,"y":10,"width":12,"height":9},"clock":{"id":"clock","x":0,"y":19,"width":3,"height":3},"todo":{"id":"todo","x":3,"y":19,"width":6,"height":4}}';

var name = "clock";
console.log(position);//before delete
delete position.name;
//delete position.name;
console.log(position);//after delete
```

I'd like to achieve this.

```
{"weather":{"id":"weather","x":0,"y":0,"width":12,"height":9},
"google_calendar{"id":"google_calendar","x":0,"y":10,"width":12,"height":9},
"todo":{"id":"todo","x":3,"y":19,"width":6,"height":4}}
```

Comment: The way you've shown the code, `position` is a string, not an object.  So, `position.name` is `undefined` because a string doesn't have a `.name` property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off `position` is a string, not an object.

Second off, `position.name` operates on the `.name` property.  If you want to operate on the property whose name is in the `name` variable, then you use `position[name]`, not `position.name`.

So, if you remove the quotes from the declaration of position or call `JSON.parse()` on it to make it into an object so it's this:

```
var position = {
    "weather": {
        "id": "weather",
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "width": 12,
        "height": 9
    },
    "google_calendar": {
        "id": "google_calendar",
        "x": 0,
        "y": 10,
        "width": 12,
        "height": 9
    },
    "clock": {
        "id": "clock",
        "x": 0,
        "y": 19,
        "width": 3,
        "height": 3
    },
    "todo": {
        "id": "todo",
        "x": 3,
        "y": 19,
        "width": 6,
        "height": 4
    }
};
```

Then, you can do this:

```
var name = 'clock';
delete position[name];
console.log(position);
```

And, that will end up deleting the `clock` property from your object.

Comment: ...and if the data *is* received as a string for whatever reason, a simple call to `JSON.parse(position)` et voilà.

Answer (score 1):

```
var position = {
    "weather": {
        "id": "weather",
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "width": 12,
        "height": 9
    },
    "google_calendar": {
        "id": "google_calendar",
        "x": 0,
        "y": 10,
        "width": 12,
        "height": 9
    },
    "clock": {
        "id": "clock",
        "x": 0,
        "y": 19,
        "width": 3,
        "height": 3
    },
    "todo": {
        "id": "todo",
        "x": 3,
        "y": 19,
        "width": 6,
        "height": 4
    }
};
```

Below statement will do your job.

```
delete position["clock"]
```